# Recognizing additional properties a vb6 app is launched with

Tags: vb6

If for example, after I compile **myapp.exe** with vb6, when I open it as

> **myapp.exe "something"**

(from Run or something), is there anyway of knowing what "something" is when your application opens, so that the application can act differently with every value of "something"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it's called a command line argument, and is returned by [Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262696%28v=vs.60%29.aspx), as in :

```
Dim commandLineArgs As String = Command
```